# Two jump with SSHPASS

Tags: ssh, sshpass

On my source server, I have SSHPASS, but not on my jump servers, and I don't have SSH KEY on either my jump or my target servers

Of course, I can't put SSHKEY neither on my JUMP nor on my TARGET
I can't install SSHPASS on my JUMP servers either

Can I access my target server through my jump server, using the sshpass of my source server?

```
+-----------------+           +-----------------+     +-----------------+
|                 |           |                 |     |                 |
| Server: Source  +-----------> Server: Jump    +-----> Server: Target  |
| sshpass: OK     |           | sshpass: NO     |     |                 |
|                 |           | No SSH KEY      |     | No SSH KEY      |
+---------+-------+           +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |
          |                   +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |                   |                 |     |                 |
          |                   | Server: Jump    |     | Server: Target  |
          +-------------------> sshpass: NO     +----->                 |
          |                   | No SSH KEY      |     | No SSH KEY      |
          |                   +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |
          |                   +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |                   |                 |     |                 |
          |                   | Server: Jump    |     | Server: Target  |
          +-------------------> sshpass: NO     +----->                 |
          |                   | No SSH KEY      |     | No SSH KEY      |
          |                   +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |
          |                   +-----------------+     +-----------------+
          |                   |                 |     |                 |
          |                   | Server: Jump    |     | Server: Target  |
          +-------------------> sshpass: NO     +----->                 |
                              | No SSH KEY      |     | No SSH KEY      |
                              +-----------------+     +-----------------+
```

Comment: please describe how you manually login to the target server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.